# How can I enable HTTPS in docker for my minimal API container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, https, dockerfile, self-signed-certificate

I have already containerized my minimal api written in c# in docker and instead of accessing the api with http://localhost:7113, I want to enable https://localhost:7114 (over HTTPS).

I have already exported a selfsigned certificate ('MinimalApi.pfx') and placed in the root of my application.

I have used this command to make a selfsigned certificate and exporting the certificate in *.pfx format:

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -KeySpec Signature -Subject "CN=MinimalApiRootCert" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -HashAlgorithm sha256 -KeyLength 2048 -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyUsageProperty Sign -KeyUsage CertSign
```

In my appsettings.json I have allowed Urls for both http and https:

```
 {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Urls": "http://*;https://*"
}
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MinimalApi/MinimalApi.csproj", "MinimalApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MinimalApi/MinimalApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MinimalApi"
COPY ["MinimalApi/MinimalApi.pfx", "/etc/ssl/certs/"]
RUN dotnet build "MinimalApi.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./MinimalApi.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MinimalApi.dll"]
```

I am also copying my 'MinimalApi.pfx' into "/etc/ssl/certs/" in my dockerfile.

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      driver: default
services:
  minimalapi-app:
    image: minimalapi-image
    ports:
      - '7113:7113'
      - '7114:7114'
    networks:
      - default
volumes:
  minimalapi-app:
    driver: local
```

However my docker container listens to port 8080 and only on HTTP. How can I enable HTTPS with my selfsigned certificate? Preferably on port '7114:7114' or '7114:443'?

I tried messing with a reversed proxy approach with Nginx, but I am really just looking for a simple solution with a selfsigned certificate only running locally on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

You might find that using NGINX is the easiest approach. I don't claim to be an expert, but I think that something like this should work.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "7113:80"
      - "7114:443"
    depends_on:
      - api
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./certificates:/etc/ssl/certs/self-signed
    networks:
      - default

  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: .
    networks:
      - default

networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      driver: default
```

I've got self-signed certificates in `certificates/`. These are volume mounted to `/etc/ssl/certs/self-signed` on the NGINX container.

`nginx.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://api:8080/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name localhost;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/self-signed/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/self-signed/server.key;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://api:8080/;
    }
}
```

This configuration will look in `etc/ssl/certs/self-signed/` for the certificates.

It will serve both HTTP and HTTPS separately. If you want to redirect HTTP to HTTPS then you'd use something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

- The API is listening on port 8080.
- NGINX will proxy port 8080 to port 80 (for HTTP) and port 443 (for HTTPS).
- Docker Compose will map port 80 to port 7113 (as specified in your question).
- Docker Compose will map port 443 to port 7114 (as specified in your question).

Comment: I appreciate your time, but as I wrote in my question in the end, I am not looking for a reversed proxy approach w. NginX. 
My mininmal api is so simple in nature, that I just want to have it enabled with HTTPS selfcontained, without introducing an extra layer.

Comment: I believe that NGINX or something similar is correct approach. Otherwise your API code has to handle the SSL. Better to just let the API do it's thing and NGINX handle the SSL. Separation of concerns.